# Change active sheet based on selected item from a dropdown list

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel WorkBook with several Sheets.  I would like to be able to select from a drop down list in the "Home" Sheet and after selection is made, automatically switch to the proper Sheet and select a specific Cell.

It appeared to be easy, but I have failed time and again to make it work.
Here is an example of what I would like to do:

[image: Example]

The only code that I managed to have a little success with is the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    With Sheets("Home")
        If Cells(6, 3).Value = "A" Then
            Sheets("A").Select
            ActiveSheet.Range("B7").Select
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The problem with it is that it will not check for the value until the user moves to another sheet. Then when it comes back, it will check for it, and will take it to the correct one, but the user will be stuck in a loop without being able to go back to "Home". (I know that it will only work on cell C6, but I just wanted to try if it worked before changing the Range)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the worksheet change event, rather than activate. Try this, in the Home sheet module.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Address = "$C$6" Then
    Application.Goto Sheets(Target.Text).Range("B7")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Really helped me, Had to make some tweaks but worked in the end.

Comment: Ok please consider accepting the answer if it helped you.